# compare dates from diff tables and get the latest date

Tags: db2

I have 3 tables.

SALES
transactionNumber
salesDate
customerNumber
employerNumbet

SALESDETAIL
transactionNumbet
Productcode
Quantity

PRICEHISTORY
effectivitydate
Productcode
Unitprice

I want to compare the salesdate and effectivity date of the product to get its latest unitprice.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question

Comment: Side note - when you sell something, you should record how much you sold it for (the price), regardless of any price-history table.  It's possible for people to be quoted special prices for things, or any number of other changes.  It's a measure of insurance - the receipt.  Yes, I know it's derived information, mostly, but sometimes you want a little extra insurance.  Not that this actually solves finding the price to sell something at on the current day.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select UnitPrice
From Sales s
Inner join SalesDetail sd on s.transactionNumber = sd.transactionNumber
Inner join PriceHistory ph on ph.ProductCode = sd.ProductCode
Where salesDate =
(
    Select Max(salesDate)
    From Sales s
    Inner join SalesDetail sd on s.transactionNumber = sd.transactionNumber
    Inner join PriceHistory ph on ph.ProductCode = sd.ProductCode
)
```

Comment: My guess is the OP is looking for something that says, "what was the price for the item at the time it was sold", using `PriceHistory` as the source for that information.  This doesn't get that - it gets **all** prices (current and previous) for items sold on the most recent day.